# Getting error "APPLICATION FAILED TO START" with simple Spring Boot App

Tags: java, spring-boot

I followed this [tutorial](http://ryanjbaxter.com/2014/12/17/building-rest-apis-with-spring-boot/) to build a REST service with Spring Boot. Everything compiles fine but after booting I get this error.

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field repo in com.pearlbit.ContactRestController required a bean of type 'com.pearlbit.Contact$ContactRepository' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.pearlbit.Contact$ContactRepository' in your configuration.
```

Any idea what is wrong?

UPDATE:

Here is my "Contact" class code.

```
package com.pearlbit;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import java.util.List;

@Document
public class Contact {


    public interface ContactRepository extends MongoRepository<Contact, String> {
        List<Contact> findByLastName(String lastName);
    }


    @Id
    private String id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String address;
    private String phoneNumber;
    private String email;
    private String twitterHandle;
    private String facebookProfile;
    private String linkedInProfile;
    private String googlePlusProfile;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getPhoneNumber() {
        return phoneNumber;
    }

    public void setPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getTwitterHandle() {
        return twitterHandle;
    }

    public void setTwitterHandle(String twitterHandle) {
        this.twitterHandle = twitterHandle;
    }

    public String getFacebookProfile() {
        return facebookProfile;
    }

    public void setFacebookProfile(String facebookProfile) {
        this.facebookProfile = facebookProfile;
    }

    public String getLinkedInProfile() {
        return linkedInProfile;
    }

    public void setLinkedInProfile(String linkedInProfile) {
        this.linkedInProfile = linkedInProfile;
    }

    public String getGooglePlusProfile() {
        return googlePlusProfile;
    }

    public void setGooglePlusProfile(String googlePlusProfile) {
        this.googlePlusProfile = googlePlusProfile;
    }

}
```

I have included the interface for MongoRepository but it's still giving me the same issue. Does this need to be added somewhere else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
package hello;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

public interface ContactRepositoryextends ContactRepository<Contact, Long> {
    List<Customer> findByLastName(String lastName);
}
```

Try this. Your repository will be implemented by spring automatically.

Comment: I have this is my model class.


    public interface ContactRepository extends MongoRepository<Contact, String> {}

Does it belong there or somewhere else?

Comment: your interface nested in the Componet class. you can try to extract the interface to a alone java file and add the @Repository

Comment: This is correct. My problem was I didn't have this in a separate file.

Answer (score 0):

probably you are using a bean type is Contact$ContactRepository, but you have not create it yet, you should register a bean this type first.if you are using spring boot , you could finish this by adding the JPA starter to extends the JPA Repository interface

Comment: Can you post an example? or can you elaborate why do you think this is the case?